# Pivot table filtered on a field but slicer shows all fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2010 and have created a pivot table based on a table of base data (which is not itself filtered).

The pivot table is filtered in the 'Pivot Table Field List' and successfully displays this filtered data.
However, When I base a Slicer on this pivot table the slicer contains ALL of the contents of the filtered field and does not reflect the filter?

Can anyone advise if I can modify this behaviour so that only the required, filtered fields are displayed in the slicer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the slicer and choose "Slicer settings". Then click "Hide items with no data", here:

[image]